# Get the value of ambient light sensor on iPhone in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sensors, light, ambient

I am working on a testing project which is trying to get the value of the ambient light sensor in iPhone and check whether the values are accurate or not. I have searched through the developer documentation, and I only found a type property called ambientLightSensor that may help. Is there any suggestions on accessing the value of the ambient light sensors in iPhone? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://www.researchandcare.org/resources/accessing-sensorkit-data/) for a starting point.